# Optaplanner and Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, solver, optaplanner, pyomo

I'm currently using `pyomo` environment to solve optimization problems. I have used different solvers (`Ipopt`, `glpk`, `cbc`, `couenne`) in order to solve my problems.

Actually I need to solve a non-linear problem with a global solver. I've already tried `couenne` but it doesn't give me the right answer. Looking on the web, I have seen the `Optaplanner` as a metaheurist solver but I only found example written in Java.

Is it possible to use this solver with `pyomo` on windows?
If yes then how to configure it?

Comment: 1. Pyomo doesn't interface with Optaplanner so no. Optaplanner gives you complete freedom in how you model your problem, but it runs on the JVM. So you'd have to a JVM language to interface with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use OptaPlanner in pyomo, but you can use OptaPlanner on Windows. Just download (or git clone) [the quickstarts here](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts). If you don't like Java, take a look at the Kotlin quickstart.

**Update**: You can now also try [OptaPy in Python](https://pypi.org/project/optapy/).